# Неправильная ориентация экрана в системе. Android MTK

Tags: android, прошивка

После прошивки планшета (Digma 9505 3g, процессор MTK, Android 5.1) ориентация изображения всегда отличается от нужной на 90 градусов, тачскрин при этом работает правильно, но не синхронно с изображением (чтобы вытащить верхнюю шторку - мне нужно свайпнуть от середины правого края экрана к центру). Проблема именно в изображении, оно смещено. Подскажите, какой файл править, чтобы вернуть изображению на экране правильную ориентацию?

Answer (score 0):

Просто нужно было подобрать правильную комбинацию из файлов boot.img и lk.bin (взял их из другой прошивки). Остальные файлы оставил те же. Все проблемы решились.